# determine if the integral converges or diverges, and evaluate the integral if it converges

Tags: calculus

I am to evaluate $\int \limits _0^\infty \frac{e^x}{e^{2x}+3}dx$

I tried using substitution but it failed because the derivative of $e^{2x}+3$ is $2e^{2x}$, not $e^x$.

I also can't use integration by parts because the integral I get when I take $u$ to be $\frac{1}{e^{2x+3}}$ is even more tricky, and I can't take it $dv$ because I cannot integrate it either.

I also thought of using comparison theorem with the hope that I will find the integral to be divergent, in which case I would not have to evaluate the integral but I couldn't find the appropriate function to use. I am out of ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $M>0$, the consider $\int \limits _0^M\frac{e^x}{e^{2x}+3}dx.$

With the the substitution $t=e^x$ we get

$$\int \limits _0^M\frac{e^x}{e^{2x}+3}dx= \int \limits _1^{e^M}\frac{1}{t^2+3}dt.$$

Caan you procced ? At the end do not foget $M \to \infty.$

Answer (score 1):

Denote: $e^x=t,e^xdx=dt$. Then:
$$\int \limits _0^\infty \frac{e^x}{e^{2x}+3}dx=\int \limits _1^\infty \frac{1}{t^2+3}dt=\frac1{\sqrt3}\int \limits_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+(t/\sqrt3)^2}d(t/\sqrt3)=\\
\frac1{\sqrt3}\arctan (t/\sqrt3)|_1^\infty=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt3}-\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt3}=\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt3}. $$